Why do we have an opposing force in dynamic equilibrium?
I found this definition in my textbook about how dynamic equilibrium works. I was wondering if the opposing force is equal to the given force such that the net force is 0. Wouldn’t that mean that the object is not moving at all (against what the book is saying, that it is moving at a constant speed on a  straight line)?
For example, in the image next the definition it is said that the force of the friction is equal to the pushing force. Wouldn’t the vectors add up to 0, and the create would be still?


This question is similar to: Why does "net force" being zero not mean that the parachuter becomes stationary in the atmosphere?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


it is said that the force of the friction is equal to the pushing
force wouldn’t then the vectors add up to0 and the create would be
still)? Thanks a lot

You can push a box on a floor at constant speed. Try it. When you do it means your pushing force exactly equals the opposing kinetic friction force between the box and the floor.
Newton’s first law of motion says an object at rest or moving at constant speed in a straight line will remain at rest or continue to move at constant speed in a straight line unless acted upon by a net external force. Note my emphasis on the word net. It means forces can be involved as long as the sum of those forces is zero.
The trick is, per Newton’s second law, you have to start (accelerate) the box moving by applying a force greater than the opposing friction force. Once you start it moving you can keep it moving at constant speed by reducing your pushing force to exactly equal the opposing friction force.
Hope this helps.
